# Running a defined loop gives different time everytime

Tags: java, loops, time

I have written the below code to observe the timing of a loop function. Surprisingly, It gives me different values for each run.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            for (int attempt = 0; attempt < 10; attempt++) {
            runloop();
        }
    }

    public static void runloop() {
            long sum = 0L;
            long starttime = System.nanoTime();
            for (int x = 0; x < 1000000; x++) {
                sum += x;
            }

            long end = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Time taken:" + (end - starttime) / 1000L);
        }
    }
```

Observation :

```
Time taken:4062
Time taken:3122
Time taken:2707
Time taken:2445
Time taken:3575
Time taken:2823
Time taken:2228
Time taken:1816
Time taken:1839
Time taken:1811
```

I am not able to understand why there is such a difference in the timing.
What is the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be anything:

- Other processes running on your computer limiting the time given to Java
- Run of the garbage collector
- Loop initialization time
- ...

Comment: Is there a definite way where I can get all the timings same ?

Comment: Not that I know of. May I ask why you want the timings to be the same?

Comment: I am doing some basic performance testing for my application. I thought of  going through a sample and afterwards for my application.

Comment: I think a better way to do that is do your tests multiple times, discarding the first x results and then just calculating the average.